# How to play default button's sound on Xamarin.Android?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm making an app with using Xamarin.forms. 
You might know forms' button is not enough to use as image button if you tried one.

So I use Image as a button and add gesturerecogniger. It's working fine. 
Good thing is that I can use all Image's bindable property same like using Image. (like 'Aspect property' and else)

Only problem is that Android button has sound effect when it's pressed. 
Mine doesn't have.

How to play default button sound on Android?

[another try]

I tried to make layout and put Image and empty dummy button on it. 
But If I do this, I can't use any property of Image or Button unless I manually link it.

So I think it's not the right way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### `Xamarin.Android`:

```
var root = FindViewById<View>(Android.Resource.Id.Content);
root.PlaySoundEffect(SoundEffects.Click);
```

[Android playSoundEffect(int soundConstant)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#playSoundEffect(int))

#### `Xamarin.iOS`

```
UIDevice.CurrentDevice.PlayInputClick();
```

#### `Xamarin.Forms` via [Dependency Service](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/):

```
public interface ISound
{
    void KeyboardClick () ;
}
```

And then implement the platform specific function.

iOS:

```
public void KeyboardClick()
{
    UIDevice.CurrentDevice.PlayInputClick();
}
```

Android:

```
public View root;
public void KeyboardClick()
{
    if (root == null)
    {
        root = FindViewById<View>(Android.Resource.Id.Content);
    }
    root.PlaySoundEffect(SoundEffects.Click);
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much @SushiHangover It's almost right answer. I had to change it little bit. root = CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity.FindViewById(Android.Resource.Id.Content)

Comment: Because it's not on Activity, I can't use FindViewById. So I access current activity.

Comment: Where does the FindViewById method come from?

Comment: @Mort An activity instance

Answer (score 1):

**Xamarin Forms**:

PCL interface:

```
interface ISoundService { void Click(); }
```

Click handler:

```
void Handle_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    DependencyService.Get<ISoundService>().Click();
}
```

Android:

```
public class MainActivity {
    static MainActivity Instance { get; private set; }
    OnCreate() {
        Instance = this;
    }
}

class SoundService : ISoundService {
    public void Click() {
        var activity = MainActivity.Instance;
        var view = activity.FindViewById<View>(
            Android.Resource.Id.Content);
        view.PlaySoundEffect(SoundEffects.Click);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following:

`MonoTouch.UIKit.IUIInputViewAudioFeedback`

Interface that, together with the [UIInputViewAudioFeedback_Extensions](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.UIKit.UIInputViewAudioFeedback_Extensions/) class, comprise the UIInputViewAudioFeedback protocol.
See Also: [IUIInputViewAudioFeedback](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.UIKit.IUIInputViewAudioFeedback/#memberlist)

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.UIKit.IUIInputViewAudioFeedback/

You'll want something like this (untested):

```
public void SomeButtonFunction()
{
    SomeBtn.TouchUpInside += (s, e) => { 
        UIDevice.CurrentDevice.PlayInputClick();
    };
}
```