# How to "click" a button with sound in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, audio-player

I'm developing an application that when you press a Button it sounds as the image you Have in the button. I'm using the NuGet **SimpleAudioPlayer** but when I'm trying to import the sound the NuGet doesn't recognize the MP3 archives, I dont know what to do here is my XAML code:

```
<!--Perro-->

                   <ImageButton Grid.Row="1"
                           Grid.Column="0"
                           Source="perro.png"
                           WidthRequest="100"
                                x:Name="boton_perro"
                                Clicked="boton_perro_Clicked"
                           BackgroundColor="White"
                           HeightRequest="100"
                           CornerRadius="70"/>
```

And here is my C# code:

```
void boton_oveja_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            Player(SonidosApp.Sonidos.sonidogato.mp3);
        }


        //Metodo de reproductor.
        public void Player( string sonido)
        {
            var assembly = typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
            Stream audioStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(sonido);
            var audio = Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer.CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.Current;
            audio.Load(audioStream);
            audio.Play();
        }
```

But when Im trying to run my code it appears this error:  `Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Sonidos' does not exist in the namespace 'SonidosApp' (are you missing an assembly reference?) (CS0234) (SonidosApp)`  The route of the mp3 sounds is: SonidosApp.Sonidos but it doesnt recognize that carpet, Any ideas? Or what Im doing wrong. Thanks in advance for answering

Comment: Your button points to ``boton_perro_Clicked`` and not ``boton_oveja_Clicked``, thought I'd mention that, you may have mistakenly posted the wrong button markup..

Comment: `SonidosApp.Sonidos.sonidogato.mp3` needs to be enclosed in quotes because it is a string path, ie `"SonidosApp.Sonidos.sonidogato.mp3"`

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much for commenting, the problem was the quotes, Thank you so much,

Comment: That's great that you got it to work! If you add what worked as "Your Answer" below, then everyone will quickly see that you no longer need help :) And if someone else in the future has a similar problem, they can upvote that answer, so that it is more noticeable.

Answer (score 0):

**Xamarin.Android**:

```
var root = FindViewById<View>(Android.Resource.Id.Content);
root.PlaySoundEffect(SoundEffects.Click);
```

[Android playSoundEffect(int soundConstant)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#playSoundEffect(int))

**Xamarin.iOS**

```
UIDevice.CurrentDevice.PlayInputClick();
```

**Xamarin.Forms** via [Dependency Service](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/):

```
public interface ISound
{
    void KeyboardClick () ;
}
```

And then implement the platform specific function.

iOS:

```
public void KeyboardClick()
{
    UIDevice.CurrentDevice.PlayInputClick();
}
```

Android:

```
public View root;
public void KeyboardClick()
{
    if (root == null)
    {
        root = FindViewById<View>(Android.Resource.Id.Content);
    }
    root.PlaySoundEffect(SoundEffects.Click);
}
```

> Answer from [this post by SushiHangover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38194286/how-to-play-default-buttons-sound-on-xamarin-android)